Instagram conversation api reel message example
I've searched everywhere, and the Facebook API doesn't allow obtaining a sample message from Instagram until it passes review. Does anyone know or can provide an example of what the response looks like from the API for a message where someone sent a reel?
I tried sending a message to myself from the same account, from another account, but the Graph API doesn't return data like it does for a Facebook page, unfortunately.
